# How to toggle svg properties using Raphaeljs and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I'm making a sidebar with sliding, accordion-like areas, so that when you click on a heading the associated content toggles visibility, as per the portion of code below. The `initAccordion` function also appends an svg "+" to the headings to indicate their action.

The final task is getting the svg held in the `cross` variable to rotate by 45 degrees on each click - which is where I'm having trouble.

Obviously, the two statements in the makeButtons function aren't accessible outside their containing function. I've tried to re-factor the code, but it ends up being a jumbled mess and I can't help thinking there must be a simple solution.

```
toggleContent : function(){
    this.toggleClass('on').next().slideToggle(200);
    cross.transform("r45");
},

makeButtons : function(el) {
    var btn = Raphael(el,15,15);
    var cross = btn.path(".....");
},

initAccoridon : function(){
    $('#eventSideBar').find('h3').each(function(){
        var btn = $('<div/>', {
            class : 'sideBarBtn'
        });
        btn.appendTo(this);
        var btnContainer = btn.get(0),
            $this = $(this);
        sidebar.makeButtons(btnContainer);
        $this.on('click', function(){
            sidebar.toggleContent.call($this);
        });
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if this is better suited to the code-review section of SO - apologies if it is; I can move it on request.

[Fiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/z8y6m/1/)

**Edit**: I've managed to get part of the way there, although with multiple elements, I can't get the corresponding svg to rotate; just the last one. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/z8y6m/9/), and updated code:

```
makeSvg : function(el) {
    this.btn = Raphael(el,15,15);
    this.cross = this.btn.path(".....");
    return {
        btn : this.btn,
        cross : this.cross
    };
},

toggleContent : function(){
    if (this.hasClass('on')) {
        sidebar.cross.transform("r0");
    } else {
        sidebar.cross.transform("r45");
    };
    this.toggleClass('on');
},

initAccordion : function(){
    $('body').find('h3').each(function(){
        var btn = $('<div/>', {
            class : 'sideBarBtn'
        });
        btn.appendTo(this);

        var btnContainer = btn.get(0),
            $this = $(this);

        sidebar.makeSvg(btnContainer);

        $this.on('click', function(){
            sidebar.toggleContent.call($this);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: basic example fiddle would help to play with. Couldn't you return your cross element from makeButtons, and then pass that to your toggleContent func ?

Comment: @Ian please see the appended fiddle. Your suggestion makes sense but I'm still a bit of a JavaScript beginner, and not able to return anything useful from makeButtons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass a parameter of the relevant element or capture it somehow. This example should work for multiple objects, you'll just need to add the reverse action.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8y6m/11/)

Relevant bit...

```
var sidebar = {

    makeSvg : function(el) {
        var btn = Raphael(el,15,15);
        return btn.path(pathString).attr({fill:"#fff",stroke:"none"});
    }, 

    toggleContent : function( myCross ){
        this.toggleClass('on');
        myCross.transform("r45");
    },

    initAccordion : function(){
        $('body').find('h3').each(function(){
            var btn = $('<div/>', {
                class : 'sideBarBtn'
            });
            btn.appendTo(this);

            var btnContainer = btn.get(0),
                $this = $(this);

            var myCross = sidebar.makeSvg(btnContainer);

            $this.on('click', function(){
                sidebar.toggleContent.call($this, myCross);
            });

        });
    }
};
```